# React router - useHistory / useNavigate vs window.history.back()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a navigate back button and while checking for returning back I found two ways:

1. The native way:

```
window.history.back()
```

or

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

2. The react router way:

```
export const BackButton: FC = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
      <button
        onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
          Back
      </button>
  );
}
```

or for v5

```
export const BackButton: FC = () => {
  const { goBack } = useHistory();

  return (
      <button
        onClick={goBack}>
          Back
      </button>
  );
}
```

So I am wondering what is the differences between these ways.

I am guessing (didn't check the source code) that under the hood react router use the native way and do a bit more things, and if I am using react router then I should use the react router way but I still would like to understand the differences.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They all map back to the `window.history` object. `goBack` also is implemented as `go(-1)`. The main difference between using the `window.history` object and using the `react-router` `history` object (v5) or `navigate` function (v6) is that using `window.history` will effect navigation changes ***outside*** of React and `react-router` whereas using `history` or `navigate` will be correctly handled internally by `react-router` to update its internal routing context prior to effecting the change with the Browser.

Think of the `window.history` "way" as a sort of "global mutation" that React wouldn't be aware of or be able to handle well.

Using `window.history` will reload the page whereas using `react-router` will only update the URL in the address bar and render/rerender routes/etc internally within the app, i.e. there is no page reload and the app remains mounted and running the entire time.

Answer (score 0):

In react window.history.back() change the URL and load page while useNavigate or useHistory just re-render components that's why it is better to use it.